# Apache Spark Taking Forever to Train

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Apache Spark 2.2 and I am working with less than 1 million rows of 11 features to train a logistical regression model. Some the features may range from 0 to 50, but most are close to zero.

To train the model I am using this:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()#maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
lrModel = lr.fit(data)
```

To prepare the data I am doing a bunch of joins a filters. 
When trying to train the model on 100 rows of data, it takes about 30 minutes. 
When I save these 100 rows, which takes a while too, the model is trained in a few seconds.

I looked at this post:

[Saving DataFrame to Parquet takes lot of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903573/saving-dataframe-to-parquet-takes-lot-of-time?rq=1)

I assume my data is spread over multiple servers and when I am trying to train the model it has to gather the data. Almost like running .collect()
on the data. However, I am new to Spark so I may be wrong.

Also, when I run the training model over night, I get an out of memory error. However, people work with much larger datasets on this cluster before.

What can I do so this model trains in a reasonable amount of time?
I have tried to save the model as a csv, but that is taking far too long...

Please help me.

Edit:

spark2-submit --master yarn --num-executors 100 --conf spark.executor.memory=64G

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
  .appName("spark session example") \
  .enableHiveSupport() \
  .getOrCreate()
```

When I say save, I mean save as a csv.

```
training_dataframe.coalesce(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('file/path/file.csv', header = 'true')
```

Here is an idea of my code:
I need to label my data from whether an event happened on a specific date. So I have a for loop looping over all the business days and filtering the past 30 days from that date.

**filter one:**
I filter for a specific business day

**filter two**
I filter for 30 days before that business day
**filter three**
I filter for 14 days before that business day

**filter four**
I filter for 7 days before that business day

**join one**
I join the 7day, 14day and 30 day table with each other based on the isin
**join two**
I join the joined tables above with the label. I replace the null values with zero.

I then use VectorAssembler and I union each of these tables to a varaible outside the for loop.

I have a print statement after all of this is complete. So the part that takes a lot of time is training the model. I saved 100 rows of data to a csv which took a long time and then uploaded it and used it to train the model. When I upload and trained the model, the whole process took a minute.

When I try to directly train the model using 100 rows of data, the training part along takes 30 minutes.

How data looks before it is trained:

```
#+--------------------+-----+
# |            features|label|
# +--------------------+-----+
# |(11,[0,4,7,10],[0...|  0.0|
# |(11,[0,5,8,10],[0...|  0.0|
# |(11,[0,4,7,10],[1...|  1.0|
# |(11,[0,4,7,10],[0...|  0.0|
# |(11,[0,4,7,10],[0...|  0.0|
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimum verifiable and complete example ?

Comment: First thing, I'd try to establish where the time is spent. You say that when the data is saved (in what format? where?) the training runs quickly but the preparation itself is costly. "a bunch of joins a filters" can easily get you into trouble. Can you show query you are trying to run and elaborate on the structure of the data source?

Comment: unfortunately I am away from my computer today. Hopefully the above edit helps

Comment: anyone able to help?